# Storing thread context specific data in a Core Data NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, concurrency

I need to store thread context specific data in a block executing with a NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType thread. Here is an example of what I would like to do within the block (a simplified example of the context data I will be storing is given but you get the point):

> ```
> dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_get_current_queue();
> NSMutableDictionary *myContext = @{@"Context": @"ContextData"};
> dispatch_set_context(myQueue, (__bridge_retained void *)myContext);
> ```

But the problem is the function dispatch_get_current_queue() used to get a reference to the current queue is deprecated, so I don't want to use it. I can't see any other mechanism for retrieving a reference to this queue so I can saving context data against it. I'm now wondering if Apple have deprecated dispatch_get_current_queue() because they don't want people doing what I am trying to do - though I can't see any documentation warning about this. 1. Do you know of any reasons this is a bad thing to do? 2. Do you know of any other way to save context data relative to the current thread where the code used should also be able to work if the thread happens to be the system provided CoreDataPrivateQueue type?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the NSThread equivalent calls can be made instead. On a single system generated MOC of type NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType this works. Will update if I encounter any problems relating to thread lifetime once I have worked with it for a bit:

```
[moc performBlockAndWait:^{
    NSThread *currentThread = [NSThread currentThread];
    NSMutableDictionary *myThreadDict = currentThread.threadDictionary;
    [myThreadDict setObject:@"Some thread data" forKey:@"IRThreadData"];
}];
[moc performBlockAndWait:^{
    NSThread *currentThread = [NSThread currentThread];
    NSMutableDictionary *myThreadDict = currentThread.threadDictionary;
    NSLog(@"Retreived dictionary value = %@", [myThreadDict objectForKey:@"IRThreadData"]);
}];
```